# Swift3でRealmを使用しListを使いたいが，Listの扱いがわからない

Tags: swift, realm

いろいろ調べてみたのですが，Listという物がどういう物なのか，その扱い方がわかりません。

RealmのDBには，subDataTableに複数のDayが　登録され，思うとおりに登録されているのですが，データの取り出し方がわかりません。

```
"List<subDataTable> (\n\t[0] subDataTable {\n\t\tID = 0;\n\t\tDay = 2017-02-12 11:16:20 +0000;\n\t},\n\t[1] subDataTable {\n\t\tID = 1;\n\t\tDay = 2017-02-12 11:16:20 +0000;\n\t}\n)",
"List<subDataTable> (\n\t[0] subDataTable {\n\t\tID = 0;\n\t\tDay = 2017-02-12 11:16:20 +0000;\n\t},\n\t[1] subDataTable {\n\t\tID = 1;\n\t\tDay = 2017-02-12 11:16:20 +0000;\n\t}\n)")
```

取り出そうとすると、上記の様になってしまいます。

これを配列などで

```
ID=0
Day=2017-02-12 11:16:20 +0000
```

として取り出したいのです。

どうしたら良いのか，ご教授いただけないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

//メインデータ
class mainDataTable: Object {
    dynamic var ID = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)
    let Days = List<subDataTable>()
    dynamic var Title = String()
    dynamic var Category : categoryDataTable?
    dynamic var Memo = String()
    dynamic var Notification = false
}

//日付データ
class subDataTable: Object {
    dynamic var ID = Int()
    dynamic var Day = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)
}

//カテゴリ名
class categoryDataTable: Object {
    //dynamic var ID = Int()
    dynamic var CategoryName = String()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "CategoryName"
    }
}

class RealmConnect{
    //デフォルトRealmの取得
    let realm = try!Realm()
    //データ
    var mainData = mainDataTable()

    func dataSave(){

        // 現在の日時を取得
        let now = Date()
        //タイムゾーンの設定必要？

        let subData1 = subDataTable()
        subData1.ID = 0
        subData1.Day = now as Date
        let subData2 = subDataTable()
        subData2.ID = 1
        subData2.Day = now as Date
        //とりあえずのデータを2件つくって放り込む（Daysも2件のもの）
        mainData.ID = now as Date
        mainData.Days.append(subData1)
        mainData.Days.append(subData2)
        mainData.Title = "てすと１"
        mainData.Category?.CategoryName = "test"
        mainData.Memo = "Memo1"
        mainData.Notification = true

        //オブジェクトをRealmに追加する
        realm.beginWrite()
        realm.add(mainData)
        try! realm.commitWrite()

        let user = realm.objects(mainDataTable.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "ID", ascending: true)

        //ここでListの内容を　一件ずつ 取得したいがListの扱い方がわからない
        print(user.count)
        print(user[0])
        let userDays = [user.value(forKeyPath: "Days")!]
        print(userDays.count)

        print(userDays[0])
        for element in userDays {
            print(element)
        }
        print(user.count)   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まずこの部分が間違っています。

```
let userDays = [user.value(forKeyPath: "Days")!]
```

`value(forKeyPath:)`メソッドが必要になることはあまりないので、まだ初心者の今の段階ではこのメソッドのことは忘れましょう。

また、右辺をわざわざ`[]`で囲ってしまっているので、戻り値が配列になってしまっています。それも意図しない結果になっている原因です。

まず、次の段階で`user`には`Results`という型の変数に結果が格納されています。

```
let user = realm.objects(mainDataTable.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "ID", ascending: true)
```

たとえ１件しかない、あるいは1件も結果がないとしても、等しく`Results`型の変数に格納されています。

次の行で、`user[0]`としているように、`Results`から`mainDataTable`の要素をまず取得する必要があります。
`user[0]`のように添え字を使う方法の他に`for u in user`のようにループを使う方法などがあります。

`let u = user[0]`のように`Results`から要素を取り出したら、`mainDataTable`のプロパティに直接アクセスできます。例えば次のような形です。

```
let u = user[0]
let day = u.days[0]
...
```

あるいは、

```
let u = user[0]
for day in u.days {
    ...
}
```

とします。

Comment: 詳しく解説していただきありがとうございます。無事にデータを取り出すことが出来ました。本当に感謝いたします。